# Точка в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Какую роль занимает точка в js?
Если вам не тяжело, то можно более подробно рассказать о ней.
Какую функцию выполняет точка в примере ниже:

```js
let id = Symbol("id");
alert(id.description);
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru

Comment: А можно объяснить на простом человеческом языке)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, точка показывается, что следующий за ней идентификатор является именем свойства.

В общем виде, такое выражение называется ["точечной нотацией" (dot notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) для обращения к свойству объекта.

Comment: Просили же на простом человеческом языке! :)

Comment: @Yaant, а что там не на человеческом? :)

Comment: Получается точка нужна для работы с объектами?

Comment: Ну, русский же общепризнанно считается сложным языком. Простой - это какой-нибудь там эсперанто. :)

Comment: @Black_Viper, в данном случае - да, для обращения к свойству объекта, по ссылке есть пример, как это можно делать без точки